# Failed assertion: line 1252 pos 12: 'widget.items!.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) => item.value == widget.value).length == 1': is not true

Tags: flutter, dropdown, flutter-widget, flutter-dropdownbutton

I am getting this error in the console when I am trying to use flutter DropdownButton Widget.

> package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart': Failed assertion: line 1252 pos 12: 'widget.items!.where((DropdownMenuItem item) => item.value == widget.value).length == 1': is not true.

There is  a long traceback...
Here I am adding small code sample that will reproduce this error... Anyone can simply copy paste in `main.dart` file

```dart
// flutter import
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const BugReportApp());
}

class BugReportApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const BugReportApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BugReportApp> createState() => _BugReportAppState();
}

class _BugReportAppState extends State<BugReportApp> {
  final TextEditingController _dropdownController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Bug Report',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Flex(direction: Axis.vertical, children:[
                        DropdownButton<String>(
            value: _dropdownController.text == ""
                ? null
                : _dropdownController.text,
            items: ["hello, world", "how are you", "goodbye"]
                .map((_value) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        child: Text(
                      _value,
                    )))
                .toList(),
            onChanged: (_value) {
              setState(() {
                _dropdownController.text = _value ?? _dropdownController.text;
              });
            },
          ),
      ],),
    );
  }
}
```

I was expecting dropown to work normally but,  I don't know why it didn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code, also added some explanation in the code:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  final TextEditingController _dropdownController = TextEditingController();

  String? dropDownValue = 'hello, world'; // add one value as the defaul one which must exists in the dropdown value

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Column(
          children: [

            Flex(direction: Axis.vertical, children:[
              DropdownButton<String>(
                value: dropDownValue, // this place should not have a controller but a variable
                onChanged: (_value) {
                  setState(() {
                    dropDownValue = _value;
                  });
                },
                items: ["hello, world", "how are you", "goodbye"]
                    .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String _value) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: _value, // add this property an pass the _value to it
                    child: Text(_value,)
                )).toList(),
              ),
            ])

          ],
        ),

    );
  }

}
```

Comment: You can also pass null on `DropdownButton`'s `value`, it can take null

Answer (score 10):

You are missing `value` on `DropdownMenuItem`.

```dart
.map((_value) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
        value: _value, // this
        child: Text(
          _value,
        )))
```

Also make sure to  use `Scaffold` on home.

Answer (score 3):

please add the *VALUE* field in both **DropdownMenuItem** and **DropdownButton**  to prevent error